# Can I recover a former version of a libreoffice document?

Tags: backup, libreoffice, data-recovery, restore, versions

I've searched high and low for an answer to this and haven't been able to find one, so hopefully someone here can help.

I was working on an essay and had made substantial progress but had to take a break, so I saved it, closed Libreoffice Writer and walked away.  When I came back to start work again and opened Libreoffice Writer, it said that the document hadn't been saved and offered me a chance to recover it, which naturally and unthinkingly I took.  However, the document it so helpfully restored (and also overwrote my newer version with) was in fact a previous version, so at the moment it looks like I've lost several days' worth of work.

I've checked Ubuntu One, but it only has the updated version.  I can't click 'versions' in the file menu of libreoffice.  I've followed the instructions on this thread but with no joy (there was nothing in the folder): http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/6652/how-to-recover-former-version-of-document/

If anyone has any suggestions, I'd be enormously grateful, because at the moment I'm despairing slightly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am having a similar problem, myself. I wrote a paper for one of my college classes, and uploaded it to the dropbox, but somehow, between saving it and uploading it, the last half of my paper was lost. My teacher notified me that I was missing several pages. Because I cannot figure out how to recover the previous version, I have to rewrite the whole last half of my paper - frustrating to say the least.

Comment: Close voters, I'm voting to close as OT bug report since this was a defintie bug several years ago (I experienced it myself more than once) but which appears to be fixed, and the OP said in a comment he would file a bug report. The recent comment does not appear to be related.

Comment: Aaannnd...I now see the comment is 2 years old (the year wrapped under the month), but more reason to close.

Comment: @user271536 Dropbox has a feature to "roll back" to a previous version up to 30 days old... you may want to check it out

Comment: @chaskes, I'd suggest closing it as "off topic" - "only relevant for a short time"

Comment: @not a bad suggestion. thx.

Comment: Same thing happened to me 7 years later. What a very incredibly dumb bug.

Comment: @JohnGlen was about to complain and type the same basically when I noticed your comment lol. 7 years 3 month later the bug (or it's a feature?) is still here. Wonder is the bug cause by Ubuntu/Gnome, or LibreOffice.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably too late for that but you could try running a file recovery program like [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) on the partition the doc was saved on.

This will only work on the off-chance that the updated revision isn't occupying the same file system block as the old one. Make sure to use your partition as little as possible until the file recovery is complete. Every additional disk write holds the risk of overwriting the file you are searching for.

Also, PhotoRec has no way of discovering what your files used to be called. After running the file recovery you might have to go through a long list of documents to find the right file and revision. [Here are some pointers](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/After_Using_PhotoRec) on how you can make this process easier.

Another note: This should not happen and it's very unfortunate that it did. After all of this is done you should consider reporting a bug on LO's bug tracker (and maybe link it by editing your question). This is severe enough to warrant immediate attention.

Comment: Thanks for your swift response.  I've already tried using a similar program called Foremost which has dug up a lot of very old documents but unfortunately with no luck.  I'll send in a bug report shortly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the recovered document is a very old version, don't save it. Do a `Save As` and give it a unique name.

Then open the original document again and this time don't select the recover option. Hopefully it is more recent. Do `Save As` a different unique name.

Next search with google on if other recovery options are available. You now have 3 copies of the file:

Original `unrecovered version`

`Recovered version` from first step

Error free saved version of `unrecovered version` from second step.

When things go wrong-- save... Save... SAVE!!!!!